# How does an oscillating sprinkler like this change directions?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, fluid-mechanics

I'm trying to understand how an oscillating sprinkler like this, is able to change directions. Does it still use a four bar linkage mechanism like a traditional oscillating sprinkler?

[image]

Comment: The algorithm for that is rather simple. The incoming water stream is divided into two. Moving the sprinkler left closes the right stream and opens the left, and vv. You should see that when you disasemble it.

Answer (score 3):

Most mass-produced devices have utility patents on them. I was able to locate the one (or a very similar one) for your device:
[EP19970306109](https://patents.google.com/patent/EP0826427A2/)
[image]

> "By pushing the arm 19 in one direction the rocker member 17 is moved to the position illustrated in Figure 8 in which the inlet 15 is open
>   to enable water to enter the inlet 15 whilst the inlet 14 is blocked
>   by the member 17..."
>   
> "When water reaches the impeller 8 through the inlet 14, the
>   water flow drives the impeller in one rotational direction and when 
>   water reaches the impeller 8 through the inlet 15 the water flow drives the impeller 8 in the other rotational direction."
>   [image]